# how do you diagram relations between several services?

Tags: documentation, uml, service, diagram

not necessary an UML diagram, just a simple way to graphically document the relations between several systems...

the systems can be linked through web services, linked-servers, text files, batch processes, com+ components etc...

I was thinking about a high level map, showing which system is consumming, exposing, resources and by which means...

perhaps a deployment diagram would do, or a completely custom diagram...

what do you use to document this kind of relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create component dependency diagrams in UML.